# Notification sent from Service won't show up

Tags: java, android, service, notifications

I'm currently trying to implement a push notification into my app, that will be sent as soon as there's an internet connection. The service for checking the connection works just fine and the showNotifications() Method is being called. But the Notification won't show up in the bar. This is the code:

```
    private void showNotifications(){

    Intent intent = new Intent(APITest2.this, Start.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("notif","notify");
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(APITest2.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder= new NotificationCompat.Builder(APITest2.this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_android)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("Text")
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0,builder.build());

}
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: In which android version you are testing this code..For android version above oreo u need to create a notification channel..Are you aware of it

Comment: I'm testing in Android 28. I did not know that, will try to solve it, thanks :)

Comment: that 28 is android version pie. it is above oreo. So you need to mandatorily create Notification Channel. I have added answer to create Notification channel...Also included sound for that channel.. Check that it may help you

Comment: Tip: Read the logcat when your code doesn't behaves the way you expect

Answer (score 0):

Use notification manager like below to support all android versions

```
NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                builder.setChannelId("com.package.name");

                NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                        "com.package.name",
                        "AppName",
                        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
                );

                if (notificationManager != null) {
                    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
                }
            }

            notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

Create channel as like below,

```
Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                    .build();
            String characterSequence = "Message Alert";
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, 
                               characterSequence,NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            channel.setSound(soundUri,audioAttributes );
            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) 
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
```

You need to pass channel id here like below,

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder= new NotificationCompat.Builder(APITest2.this,channelId)
```

Also refer https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels

If you need to show heads up notification, then you need to set Importance level in Notification Channel as IMPORTANCE_HIGH. And need to set priority in notification builder as below.

```
setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
```